# How to clone git repository without network connection

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone

The infrastructure:  I have two hosts (A and B).  I cannot connect from A to B or vice versa.  There is no host C which is reachable from host A and host B.  I can send e-mails in both directions.  Text attachments are allowed.  Others attachments are not allowed.  There may be other problems ...

I want to clone a git repository from host A to host B.  I want to be able to work on both hosts.  I want to push my commits from A to B and vice versa.

Question:  Is there a simple way to transfer commits (usable with my infrastructure)?

I have tried:  I can use `git format-patch` to make text versions of my commits.  But there is only the author date in the generated files.  The committer date is missing.  And the parent commit is missing.  I can look at the other host - so I know both informations.  And then, I can use `git commit` with `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITER_DATE` to generate a commit with the correct commit-hash.

It works :)  But I have to type a few commands.  And if I want to transfer more commits, I have to type a few more commands.

Comment: `git bundle` or `tar` and then `base64` encode the whole thing? `format-patch` will result in new, different commits (author and committer dates/infos do not necessarily have to match in your original repo).

Comment: Thanks, I did not know `git bundle`.  It is easier than my `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`-`GIT_COMMITER_DATE`-hack (which preserves the dates too).  I will try it in detail, but at the moment it seems to be the solution.

Comment: Dates cannot be preserved if the original commit contained an author date different from the committer date. After the import, you will end up with both dates being identical.

Comment: I tried `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2023-04-08T00:00:00" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2023-04-09T12:34:56" git commit -m "..."`.  And then `git cat-file -p head`.  The timestamps in the `author`-line and `committer`-line are different.  So I think that with my hack, the timestamps can be preserved.  What do I misunterstand?

Comment: Yes, the dates are different. Now, create a patch with `format-patch` and apply it in another repo. What happens to the author and committer date? The author date is preserved, the committer date is "now". If you force the committer date to be the same as the author date of the patch, you now have a commit with 2 identical dates (which is different from the commit pre format-patch). Maybe I am misunderstanding and you are looking at every single commit from host A to override both author _and_ committer date?

Comment: That is, what I described as "it works".  I am able to set the correct committer and author date.  So, I can force the correct commit hash.  But the "solution" is not very good, because I have to rework every single commit.  Your suggestion `git bundle` is better.  Much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) to create an archive of refs. From the man page:

> Create, unpack, and manipulate "bundle" files. Bundles are used for the "offline" transfer of Git objects without an active "server" sitting on the other side of the network connection.
>
> They can be used to create both incremental and full backups of a repository, and to relay the state of the references in one repository to another.

Since the requirement is "text only", you could then hex- or `base64` encode the bundle to get a text representation that can be reverted on the receiving host.

Another quick-and-dirty solution is to `tar` your repo and encode as text. Using this approach cannot do incremental updates for obvious reasons.

Both solutions avoid the problem of messing with committer and author information. Setting author == committer loses information if the original repository (on host A) contains commits with distinct author and committer information.